# Question on Iterated limit sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

This question is from [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_exs.pdf) p 18:

> [image]

My try:
For $n=1$ any finite set in reals will do. For $n=2$, $E=\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$. For $n=3$, let  $E=\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots\}\cup\{1\frac 12,1\frac 13,1\frac 14,\dots\}\cup\{1\frac 34,1\frac 8{15},1\frac5{12},\dots\}\cup\dots$ and so $L(E)=\{0,1,1\frac 12,1\frac34,\dots\}$ and $L^2(E)={2}$ and $L^3(E)=\varnothing$. i can't go further.

Comment: $E=(0,1)$ thnen $L(E) = [0,1] = L^n(E)$ for all $N$..

Comment: Correcting my work ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $E_0=\{0\}$, $E_1 = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{m_1} |m_1 \in \mathbb{N} \}$,  $E_2 = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{m_1}+\frac{1}{m_2} | m_1,m_2 \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and so on. Then $L(E_n)=E_{n-1}$ and $L^{n+1}(E_n)= \phi$ and $L^n(E_n)=\{0\}$.

Comment: I can see that $E_{n-1}\subset  L(E_n)$. How to show other inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Let A = {0} $\cup$ { 1/n : n in N } for the first example.

For the second, add to A, for each nonzero point p in A
a descending sequence converging to p.  Fit the sequence
converging to 1(1 + n) between 1(1 + n) and 1\n.

Continue this way adding more and more sequences for each
next example.

Answer (score 1):

$n=1$ finite OK. Or take $\mathbb{Z}$.

For $n=1$ consider $E = \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}: n =1,2,3\}$.
For $n=2$ build on the previous one: add a convergent sequence converging to  $\frac{1}{n}$, for each $n$. And so on.